# prompt (true and false, not work)!

Tags: javascript, html, prompt, confirm

I have two option in prompt, acept and cancel, here is ok, but when I do cancel in prompt, this generate a list of anyway, why not function?

```
  add.onclick = function(){
   if(true) {
    var itemText = prompt('Create a Memo');
   }else {
    return false;
  }
```

Comment: *When I do cancel in prompt, this generate a list of anyway, why not function?* Could you rephrase that part of your question? I cannot make any sense of it in its current state.

Comment: `if(true)` is conditional on `true` which is always true, so `if` block always runs and the `else` block never runs. I'm not completely clear on what you're trying to do. Do you actually want to make the `if` block conditional on the result of the `confirm` call?

Comment: This is a good JavaScript tutorial: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide

Comment: @apsillers When i do cancel in a prompt, i have that get out of the prompt without to generate a list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var question = prompt('Create a memo');
if(question) {
    alert('true - ' + question);
} else {
    alert('false - ' + question);
}
```

<kbd>[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/j6o9g1eu/)</kbd>

Another example:

```
var question = prompt('Create a memo');
if(question) {
    document.getElementById('text').innerHTML = 'I answered ' + question;
} else {
    document.getElementById('text').innerHTML = 'I canceled';
}
```

<kbd>[**DEMO 2**](http://jsfiddle.net/j6o9g1eu/1/)</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

to get true or false in variable, use confirm statement